# SQL - defining date for observations based on three different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have three tables: Table_A, Table_B, and Table_C.

Each table contains three variables - ID, Problem, and Date. The date may or may not be missing in the tables.

I need to create a new table such that all observations have a date. Rule for achieving this: For all ID/Problem pairs in Table_A, Date from Table_A will be used as the date when Date exists. Otherwise, the minimum Date from Table_B and Table_C will be used. If Date is missing in all the tables then drop the observation.

`SELECT ID, Problem, MIN(Date) as Date
FROM
(   SELECT ID, Problem, Date
    FROM Table_A
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, Problem, Date
    FROM Table_B
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, Problem, Date
    FROM Table_C
) as subQuery
Delete From table Where Date IS NULL`

Comment: Is it MySQL or SQL-Server?

Comment: It is MySQL. Can you help me with it?

Comment: @juergend is there anything I can provide additionally?

Comment: You need to provide some sample data, and the expected result from that data. Also, is ID a unique primary key each table?  Is "Problem" text or a foreign key to a problem table?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this may get you started:

```
select id, problem, `date` from table_a where `date` is not null
union

select id, problem, min(`date`)
from (
    select id, problem, date from table_b where `date` is not null
    union all
    select id, problem, date from table_c where `date` is not null
    ) d
group by id, problem
```